# Can this clause function as an adverbial of reason?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, adverbial-phrases, functions, adverbials

I couldn’t analyse the structure of this sentence properly. Specifically, i don’t know what is the function of the clause “over giving weighting factor to the role of youngsters.”

This is the whole sentence:

> There has been a lot of controversy among people over giving weighting factor to the role of youngsters.

Can the second clause (over giving...youngsters) function as an adverbial of reason??

Comment: The sentence is ungrammatical. "Factor" is a count noun that requires a determiner such as "a" or "the". Where did you find it? Incidentally, the clause is just "giving weighting factor to the role of youngsters". "Over" is a preposition and the clause is its complement. The whole PP then functions as complement of "controversy".

Comment: I’ve found it in an article published in a high school magazine. Thank you for the correction and for the answer:)